# Prefetch doesn’t sum the field

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

My queryset is

```
product = Prosucts.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch(‘prod_sale’, Sales.objects.filter(type__in=(1,2)).annotate(quantity_sold=Sum(‘quantuty’)), to_attr=‘prod_sold’))
```

So if I have product juice=3, apple =6, apple=4

My queryset gives me juice = 3, apple = 6 , 4

I can’t get Apple to be 10

Comment: What is sim? ;)

Comment: sorry its a typo, I wanted to say Sum

Comment: Prefetch is used to get objects with  related names  which is linked by a foreignkey, not to sum up. You would need to use  annotate.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had a look at your models.py am assuming your related name for Product object model and Sales object is 'prod_sale’ ,which i used to link both models with the prefetch_related and then annotate the sum. This is just to give you an idea on how to go about it.  Here is a link to read more on aggregating and annotating sums: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/

```
product = Products.objects.all().prefetch_related('prod_sale’).annotate(quantity_sold=Sum(‘quantity’)))
```